# Sharepoint - Provisioning xsl Style Files

Tags: 2007, deployment, content-query-web-part, xslt

I'm trying to provision a .xsl file with custom styles to be applied to a `Content Query Web Part` in SP 2007 MOSS. I want to deploy it in a feature.
So far any attempt has failed as I cannot retrieve my .xsl in the Style Library.

```
 <!-- Feature.xml -->
 <ElementManifests>
     <ElementManifest Location="Elements.xml" />
     <ElementFile Location="Test.xsl" />
 </ElementManifests>



 <!-- Elements.xml -->
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Module Name="Test" Url="Style Library/XSL Style Sheets" Path="" RootWebOnly="FALSE">
     <File Url="Test.xsl" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
   </Module>
 </Elements>
```

There are no errors in the log files. For what I've seen on the web, this should work but it doesn't.

Comment: can you past the directory structure of your feature ? maybe a path related problem...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it does not work because you set RootWebOnly="FALSE". The Style Library is a site collection thing. Try to set it to TRUE, activate the feature and see what happens. If you still cannot see the file/folder in the style library connect to it with SharePoint designer and check if it can see the file/folder.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one thing, but it might not be a necessity: If your xsl-file is in a module, the Path attr. of the Module element should point to that, e.g. Path="MyModule". You can also try to add Path="Test.xsl" to the File element as well.

Both *should* not be necessary afaik though (You *should* have gotten an errormsg if the file was not found)